# how to find sum of even digit in plsql?

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, modulo

```
declare
       n number(4);
       s number(4);
       i number(4);
     count number(4);

begin
       n:=&n;
       s:=0;
       count:=0;

       while (n>0 AND count MOD 2 = 0)
       loop
              i:= n mod 10;
              s:=s+i;
              n:=trunc(n / 10) ;  
              count:=count+1;  
       end loop;

       dbms_output.put_line('Sum of digit = ' || s);

end;
```

I have tried it but getting error:

```
ERROR at line 12:
ORA-06550: line 12, column 23:
PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'COUNT' may be used inside a SQL statement
only
ORA-06550: line 12, column 8:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Please, add your error description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must rename COUNT variable because it is reserved word in Oracle.

But I am not sure that your logic is right.

First step - `cnt=0, mod(cnt , 2) = 0`, you inside your loop

Second step - `cnt=1, mod (cnt,2) = 1`, you will not step inside cycle and `while` will be ended. Maybe you should do `IF MOD(cnt,2) = 0 THEN ....`

I renamed `count` to `cnt`

Comment: // yes i tried with if but not working in it .. just finding logic now

Answer (score 0):

[`MOD` is a function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/mod.php), not an operator. Try:

```
while (n > 0 AND MOD(count, 2) = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

count should be "count" bcz it's reserved word  condition in    **while** is not correct. if as in sample below n=150 result will be zero

```
declare
           n number(4);
           s number(4);
           i number(4);
           "count" number(4);


begin
       n:=150;
       s:=0;
       "count":=0;

       while (n>0)
       loop
              i:= n mod 10;
              s:=s+i;
              n:=trunc(n / 10) ;  
              if ("count" MOD 2 = 0)
              then             
                "count":="count"+1;  
              end if;  
       end loop;

       dbms_output.put_line('Sum of digit = ' || s);

end;
```